# Resize table columns in Google Docs like AutoFit Contents in Microsoft Word

Tags: google-docs

In Microsoft Word, you can resize column widths automatically using **AutoFit Contents** from the **Layout** ribbon's **AutoFit** pulldown menu.  This resizes the selected table such that column widths are no wider than they need to be to display the content.

This can obviously be done by manually resizing columns in Google Docs, but is there a way to automate it the way the Excel function does?  [This doesn't seem to be available in Google Docs directly](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0Yyb1KcAFwDk/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fdocs%2FYyb1KcAFwDk), but is there some add-on or other method to accomplish this?

Comment: manual method still works

Comment: That it does, but with content-determined column widths changing regularly as a document is edited, it's not very convenient.  I'll edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the column
Click inside the shaded area
Click the 3 dots at the end
Scroll down and select the option ... Resize column
Click the first option ... fit to data
Save

You may need to repeat this from time to time